# Bug? MVC5: EF6 wants to delete database on LINQ query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Until yesterday I had a perfectly fine working database with seeded test data.
Then I ran an "update-package" since a long time. It updated almost every ASP package.

I deleted the DB and recreated it, test data was created perfectly by the Seed method.
So far so good.

Now when I try to access the DB in **any** way, like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Games.ToList());
    }
```

I get this error on that db.Games.ToList():

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot drop database “DataBaseName” because it is currently in use.

Obviously there is no reason for the "system" to think, that I want to delete the database. That's only a select query. Like I said, this happens on any db query.

Of course I could undo the whole "update-package", but actually that is not what I want to do.

Is this a bug? Did I miss something?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How do you delete and recreate database?

Comment: I delete it via SQL Connection Explorer or SQL Management Studio. Then I run "update-database" in the package manager console to recreate.

Comment: An what `Seed` method you are talking about?

Comment: This is a template method by ASP/EF where I can initialize the database with test data. It runs automatically on every "update-database"

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was the EntityFramework package.
I upgraded from 6.0.0 to 6.1.1 and got the error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot drop database “DataBaseName” because it
>   is currently in use.

When I upgraded from 6.0.0 to 6.0.1, a smaller update step, the error was way more specific (and different)

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The DropCreateDatabaseAlways initializer did
>   not drop or create the database backing context 'ApplicationDbContext'
>   because Migrations are enabled for the context. Use Migrations to
>   manage the database for this context, for example by running the
>   'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console.

EF had a problem because I used a DropCreateDatabase Initializer AND migrations.
Looks like from version 6.0.1 onwards, EF doesn't like that anymore (I know it was useless anyway).

Nevertheless I don't understand why they changed this error in the later versions...